# how to pass data to a ViewModel in WP8 C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, mvvm

i have a List that i would like to pass to the ViewModel.Intuitively i thought it would be straightforward by passing it is a parameter to the ViewModel's constructor but on doing that i get the error that a ViewModel's constructor should be parameterless...This being the case:

```
public SomeMethod(){
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(list);
   }
```

the viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> Collection { get; set; }

    public ViewModel(List<T> t)
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        foreach (T item in t)
        {
              this.Collection.Add(new T (item.value));
        }
    }
```

what other ways can i pass the list to the ViewModel..for one i thought of creating another method in the ViewModel that  accepts the list as a parameter,but how would i be able to call it from the constructor since the constructor  has to pass the parameter to it too.

Comment: You can create second parameterless constructor.

Comment: you can add a parameter less constructor\ default constructor. in Visual Studio type ctor and press TAB

Comment: @Yuri i created that already but on linking with the XAML side,it still points to the parameterless constructor and not the other one ,since it expects irt to be parameterless...something like this: <local:ViewModel/>

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747649/how-to-bind-view-to-viewmodel-with-parameters. You need to use dependency injection to pass parameters to viewmodel when binding in XAML.

Comment: If you use MEF you can have a parameter-less constructor and DI properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the Constructor empty and modify your `Collection`-Property to Property with Backing field.

After this, you can do in your setter whatever you want.

```
    private ObservableCollection<T> _collection
    public ObservableCollection<T> Collection { 
get{
return this._collection;
} 
set{
this._collection = value; 
// Do what you want here 
}
```